# Are medical terminology definitions considered off-topic?

Tags: discussion

[This](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/64943/22020/) is the post in question. It's the first that I've seen a post of this kind since I've been active on Biology.SE, and I'm wondering: if the OP *literally* only asks for the meaning/origin of a medically related word (no example, no elaboration, nothing), is that still considered on-topic?

Wouldn't that kind of question be just as suited, if not better, in, perhaps, an English/Language/Literature site of SE?

Comment: I think that should be off-topic since it really has nothing to do with biology.

Comment: That was my initial thought too. And a few hours later, I'm still thinking the same.

Comment: I've added the terminology tag. The question lacks prior research effort I suppose, so it could be closed on that term perhaps.

Comment: [Similar type of question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/31254/why-do-people-in-the-scientific-community-use-terminology-such-as-renal-hepatic), which however leads to some biological connections in the answer.

Comment: @fileunderwater I find your linked post slightly different than what I'm putting under scrutiny. In the post you link to, the OP is asking for differences between the terms and how they're used. In the case of my provided post, the user is actually asking the etymology of the words, which is quite different.